# Using Autocomplete in Newform.aspx customization

Tags: jquery-ui, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-jsom

I am trying to use the auto complete option in Jquery with SharePoint 2013 .

I have tried the below code

```
     var autocomplete = $("input[title='Skill Required Field']").autocomplete({
minLength: 3,
source: function( request, response ) {
$.ajax({
beforeSend: function (request)
{
request.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose;charset=utf-8");
},
url: site url,
dataType: "json",
success: function( data ) {
$.each(data.d.results , function ( i, result ) {
if(result.Title){
titles.push(result.Title)
}                               
});
response(titles);
},
error: function( data ) {
alert('search error');
}
});
},
// Run this when the item is in focused (not selected)
    focus: function( event, ui ) {
    return false;
    },
// Run this when the item is selected
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        location.href = ui.item.fields.Path;
    },
appendTo: $('#menu-container')
}).data( "uiAutocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
return $("<li>").append('<div>' + item.label + '</div>' ).appendTo( ul );
};

function getFields(results) {
r = {};
for(var i = 0; i< results.length; i++) {
if(results[i] != undefined && results[i].Key != undefined) {
r[results[i].Key] = results[i].Value;
                }
            }
            return r;
        }
```

I am customizing the new form.aspx . I have added a JSLink, in which the data for the skill is defined as below:

```
"<div id='menu-container' class = 'col-xs-3'>{{SkillCtrl}}</div>",

formTable = formTable.replace("{{SkillCtrl}}", getSPFieldRender(ctx, "MySkill"));
```

The column is created as a single line of text. I am using jquery-ui-1.12.1 , jquery-1.11.3.min.
Currently I am not getting any error, but the results do not show in the menu container box. When using F12, I can see the data in "result.Title". However, there is no data shown in the UI. What am I missing? How to fix this?Thanks

Comment: Results need to be returned to `response()` and I do not see that in your example. Also I do not see where `<input type="text" title="Skill Required Field" />` exists in your example code.

Answer (score 0):

I would try the following `success` code:

```
success: function(data) {
  var titles = [];
  $.each(data.d.results, function(i, result) {
    if (result.Title) {
      titles.push(result.Title);
    }
  });
  response(titles);
}
```

Also, when you renderItems, you must wrap them correctly: `<li><div></div></li>`. I would advise:

```
return $("<li>").append('<div><img style="margin-right:3px;top:3px;" src="/_layouts/15/images/' + img + '">' + item.label + '</div>').appendTo(ul);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I corrected those. But still the data is not shown in the UI. I tried for an item, the return li statement is hit 3 times, but no data is reflected back in the Ui. I have updated my existing code with the changes I have made

Comment: @venkat14 I would add `console.log(data)` in your `success` callback and then check to see that the data you are getting back from your AJAX call is what you expect. Could you also edit your post and include an example of what `data` looks like?